# Is there a cleaner way to extract JSON data stored in a SQL column and convert it into a new column while keeping it SQL Server 2008 compatible?

Tags: json, sql-server, subquery

I've got a table of Employee data that, if you put two results in a CSV file, looks something like this :

```
Usage,EmployeeID,EmailAddress,Name,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,GlobalID,Birthdate,UsageTags,NameAliases,ActiveDepartments,ADPriority
SupervisorOfStudents,10039,DLname@schoolname.edu,Dr. Fname M. Lname,Lname,Fname,M,NULL,NULL,"[{""seqNo"":1,""Tag"":""Employee:Active""},{""seqNo"":2,""Tag"":""Employee:ActiveChair""},{""seqNo"":3,""Tag"":""Employee:ActiveFaculty""},{""seqNo"":4,""Tag"":""Employee:InActiveStaff""}]","[{""seqNo"":1,""Name"":""Lname,Fname M""}]","[{""DepartmentType"":""Employee"",""Departments"":[{""seqNo"":1,""DepartmentId"":""99901"",""DepartmentName"":""Chemistry""},{""seqNo"":2,""DepartmentId"":""99902"",""DepartmentName"":""School of Science""},{""seqNo"":3,""DepartmentId"":""99903"",""DepartmentName"":""Continuing Education""}]}]",1
SupervisorOfStudents,10079,FLname@schoolname.edu,Ms Fname M. Lname,Lname,Fname,M,NULL,NULL,"[{""seqNo"":1,""Tag"":""Employee:Active""},{""seqNo"":2,""Tag"":""Employee:ActiveManager""},{""seqNo"":3,""Tag"":""Employee:ActiveStaff""},{""seqNo"":4,""Tag"":""Student:Attended""}]","[{""seqNo"":1,""Name"":""Lname,Fname M""},{""seqNo"":2,""Name"":""Lname,Fname Middle""},{""seqNo"":3,""Name"":""Lname-laLastName,Lname Fname""}]","[{""DepartmentType"":""Employee"",""Departments"":[{""seqNo"":1,""DepartmentId"":""99801"",""DepartmentName"":""Athletics""}]}]",1
```

I need to write a query that's SQL Server 2008 compatible that does the following:
It needs to return a row for each employee per department that they are in, so for example, Dr. Lname would show up three times -- once for Chemistry, School of Science, and Continuing Education (respectively) while Ms. Lname would only show up once -- for the Athletics department.
The Department Name and the Department ID need to be columns in this query.

I came up with something that uses a couple of subqueries but I feel as though it could be cleaner.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT
    Usage,
    EmployeeID,
    EmailAddress,
    Name,
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    GlobalID,
    Birthdate,
    UsageTags,
    NameAliases,
    DepartmentName,
    DepartmentId
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Usage,
            EmployeeID,
            EmailAddress,
            Name,
            LastName,
            FirstName,
            MiddleName,
            GlobalID,
            Birthdate,
            UsageTags,
            NameAliases,
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('"DepartmentName":"', ActiveDepartments) > 0 THEN
                    SUBSTRING(
                        ActiveDepartments, 
                        CHARINDEX('"DepartmentName":"', ActiveDepartments) + LEN('"DepartmentName":"'), 
                        CHARINDEX('"', ActiveDepartments, CHARINDEX('"DepartmentName":"', ActiveDepartments) + LEN('"DepartmentName":"')) - CHARINDEX('"DepartmentName":"', ActiveDepartments) - LEN('"DepartmentName":"')
                    )
                ELSE NULL
            END AS DepartmentName,
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('"DepartmentId":"', ActiveDepartments) > 0 THEN
                    SUBSTRING(
                        ActiveDepartments, 
                        CHARINDEX('"DepartmentId":"', ActiveDepartments) + LEN('"DepartmentId":"'), 
                        CHARINDEX('"', ActiveDepartments, CHARINDEX('"DepartmentId":"', ActiveDepartments) + LEN('"DepartmentId":"')) - CHARINDEX('"DepartmentId":"', ActiveDepartments) - LEN('"DepartmentId":"')
                    )
                ELSE NULL
            END AS DepartmentId
        FROM
            vwSupervisors
    ) AS DepartmentInfo
WHERE
    Usage = 'SupervisorBasicInfo';
```

...This feels messy. Is there a cleaner way to do this without breaking SQL Server 2008 Compatibility?

I've done some Googling, but I'm not really a SQL guy, so I haven't found anything compatible. I thought that JSON_VALUE or OPENJSON might do it, but they're not compatible with SQL Server 2008...

Comment: SQL Server 2008 ended support [4 years ago](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/end-support-sql-server-2008). You really should upgrade.

Comment: The way to keep compatibility with such an old, and unsupported, version is to *not* use that version to do the work. Do the consumption outside of SQL Server and don't store the JSON in SQL Server, as you won't be able to parse it there.